# Explanation of XDMP-EXTIME in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need a lucid explanation of why `XDMP-EXTIME` happens in Marklogic. In my case it's happening during a search(read operation). In the exception message a line from the code is being printed:

> XDMP-EXTIME: wsssearch:options($request, $req-config) -- Time limit exceeded

This gives me the impression that the execution does not go beyond that line. But it seems that it's a pretty harmless  line of code ,it does not fetch any data from the DB, just sets certain search options. How can I pin point which part of the code is causing this? I have heard that increasing the max time limit of the task server solves such problems but that's not an option with me. Please let me know how such problems are tackled. It would be very very  hard for me to show you the code base.Still hoping to hear something helpful from you guys.

Answer (score 3):

The error message can sometimes put you on the wrong foot because of lazy evaluation. The execution can actually be further down the road than the error message seems to indicate. Could be one line, could be several. Look for where the returned value is being used.

Profiling can sometimes help getting a clearer picture of where most time is spent, but the lazy evaluation can throw things off here as well.

The bottom-line meaning of the message is pretty simple: the execution of your code takes too long. The actual search in which the options are being used is the most likely candidate of where it goes wrong.

If you are using cts:search or search:search under the covers, then that should normally perform well. A search typically gets slow when you end up returning many results, e.g. don't apply pagination. Search:search does that by default however.

A search can also get slow if you are running your search in update mode. You could potentially end up having MarkLogic trying to apply many (unnecessary) read locks. Put the following declaration in your search endpoint code, or xquery main module that does the search:

```
declare option xdmp:update "false";
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You could try profiling the code to see what specifically is taking so long. This might require increasing the session time limit temporarily to prevent the timeout from occurring while profiling. Note that unless this is being executed on the Task Server via `xdmp:spawn` or `xdmp:spawn-fucntion`, you would need to increase the value on the App Server hosting the script.

If your code is in a module, the easiest thing to do is make a call to the function that times out from Query Console using the Profile tab. Alternatively, you could begin the function with `prof:enable(xdmp:request())` and later output the contents of `prof:report(xdmp:request())` to a file on the filesystem, or insert it somewhere in the database.

Comment: thank you. yes i will profile and see what comes up.